# How do I calculate hash value of specific file in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am new to batch scripting and I am having troubles in a few lines trying to calculate hash value of a specific file.

I am writing a script to check for a file that I will be sending from one place to another. To check that the files are identical, I need to calculate the hash value of the file before it was sent and after it was sent to compare the hash value to make sure it is identical. Below is my code that I have written to calculate and compare the hash value of the file.

```
set original=CertUtil -hashfile \\172.168.101.187\smb\1GBTESTFILE.TXT MD5
set received=CertUtil -hashfile \\172.168.101.188\smb\1GBTESTFILE.TXT MD5
if original==received(
echo no file lost
) else (
echo file lost
)
```

I should be expecting 'no file lost' however, I am receiving "The syntax of the command is incorrect".

Comment: You cannot use `set` to store the output of a command into a variable, you need to use [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) instead; also note that `CertUtil` returns more than just the hash value. N. B.: there is a space missing in front of the opening parentheses in the `if` command line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `set` to store the output of a command into a variable, you need to use a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) instead. Also note that `CertUtil` returns more than just the hash value:

```cmd
rem /* At first, clear variable that is going to receive the hash value;
rem    then use `for /F` to capture the output of `CertUtil`, skipping the first line,
rem    which merely contains the text `MD5 hash of file`, the file name/path and `:`;
rem    the `if defined` line ensures that only the second line of the output is captured,
rem    so the summary line `CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.` is dismissed;
rem    the `2^> nul` part avoids error messages by `CertUtil`: */
set "ORIGINAL=" & for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%H in ('
    2^> nul CertUtil -hashfile "\\172.168.101.187\smb\1GBTESTFILE.TXT" MD5
') do if not defined ORIGINAL set "ORIGINAL=%%H"
rem // Same procedure for the second hash value:
set "RECEIVED=" & for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%H in ('
    2^> nul CertUtil -hashfile "\\172.168.101.188\smb\1GBTESTFILE.TXT" MD5
') do if not defined RECEIVED set "RECEIVED=%%H"
rem /* Conditional actions; regard that you need surrounding `%%` to read variables;
rem    also note the spaces in front of `(`!: */
if "%ORIGINAL%%RECEIVED%"=="" (
    >&2 echo ERROR: no hashes available!
) else (
    if "%ORIGINAL%"=="%RECEIVED%" (
        echo INFO:  hashes match.
    ) else (
        if "%ORIGINAL%%RECEIVED%"=="%RECEIVED%%ORIGINAL%" (
            >&2 echo ERROR: one hash is missing!
        ) else (
            >&2 echo ERROR: hashes differ!
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Should be noted that this function does not account for missing files, it will say "mismatch" if one of the MD5 aren't calculated. This could be a good thing if one wants to handle that situation in the same way.

Comment: @MikeQ, meanwhile I amended the script to account for the situation when one of the two files is missing…

Comment: Thanks for doing that, however need to account for one or both not having a value set: if "%ORIGINAL%"=="" Set "MISSING=TRUE"
if "%RECEIVED%"=="" Set "MISSING=TRUE"
If "%MISSING%"=="TRUE" (
    >&2 echo ERROR: no hashes available!
)

Comment: @MikeQ, this should already be covered by the condition `if "%ORIGINAL%%RECEIVED%"==""`…

Comment: @aschipfi no because you are only checking for when BOTH are not set and not one or the other not being set